# Append image to td element with no id or value

Tags: javascript, html, append

I have an array of image elements, I use a function to randomize the array and I would like to append them back to the HTML table in their randomized order. However I am trying to avoid giving each td element it's own id because there are quite a few...I am wondering if it's possible to append the image to the td element with  it not having a id.

The HTML table has about 12 rows that would be like this:

```
    <table class="piecetray">
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
    etc...
```

JS

```
function randomizePieces(myArray) { 
  for (var i = myArray.length - 1; i > 0; i--) { 
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1)); 
    var temp = myArray[i]; 
    myArray[i] = myArray[j]; 
    myArray[j] = temp; 
  } 
return array; 
}
```

Comment: What do your values looks like?  What is being returned from the random function?

Comment: @JoePacker the function returns the an array of random order, like this:     function randomizePieces(myArray) {
               for (var i = myArray.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                  var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
                  var temp = myArray[i];
                  myArray[i] = myArray[j];
                  myArray[j] = temp;
               }
           return array;
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the table is already built and you want to iterate through each `td` and update it's background with just plain js.

```
// lets start by getting the `table` element
var tbl = document.getElementsByClassName("piecetray");

// lets get all the child rows `tr` of the `table`
var trs = tbl[0].childNodes[1].getElementsByTagName("tr");
var trlen = trs.length;

//just a test image 
var host = "http://upload.wikimedia.org";
var img = host + "/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/25/Red.svg/200px-Red.svg.png";

// iterate over the rows `tr`
for (var i = 0; i < trlen; i++) {
    //get the `td`s for this row
    var tds = trs[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    var tdlen = tds.length;

    //iterate over the cells `td`
    for (var n = 0; n < tdlen; n++) {
        //set `backgroundImage`
        tds[n].style.backgroundImage = "url(\"" + img + "\")";
    }

}
```

See the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ghLu1pp/6/), hopefully this at least points you in the right direction.

Comment: Hmm, this looks like something very useful, however they aren't background images, the table is already constructed with image elements inside each td element like <td><img src="media/hrt2.jpg"></td> because the images are shapes that are being dragged by the user and placed in another table. I need to have the images location randomized on each new turn, and when the page loads so that they can not remember where each shape lies. Would this work even though they are not background images?

Comment: Obviously I'm trying to go off only the information you have supplied, this logic gives you the ability to iterate your table however, you could change the contents accordingly, the point of `tds[n]` will be the actual `td` element, so you could do anything you need to do to this element here.

Comment: You could instead `tds[n].appendChild(randomShape())` and make a method `var randomShape = function() { return "<img src=\"media/hrt2.jpg\">" }` that returns your random object as markup/string?, I'm not quite sure what you're actually doing to assist further.

Comment: Added some slight modifications, but this was very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the basic idea of what you are looking for.

```js
$('#table').html(''); //clear the table

for(var x = 0, len = array.length; x < len; x++){ //fill the table
  $('#table').append('<tr>');
  $('#table').append('<td>' + array[x] + '</td>'); //can also add img tag here if you get the SRC for the image
  $('#table').append('</tr>');
}
```

```html
<table id="table"></table>
```

Comment: OP doesn't appear to be using JQuery, answering with JQuery is not the most helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately I am doing this for a project in which we are not allowed to use J Query

Answer (score 0):

Would it be something like that

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

$.each($('.piecetray tr td'), function(index, value){
    var img = $('<img />').attr('src', '').attr('title', index);
        $(value).append(img);
});
```

});

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mike_123/x1mjqrc1/)

Comment: Unfortunately I am doing this for a project in which we are not allowed to use J Query

Comment: It seem the answer bellow does it without jquery